# Random Link PHP

Tags: php, random, hyperlink

***EDITED***

I'm trying to setup a random link at the bottom of all my pages. I'm using the code below, but want to make it so the current page is not included in the random rotation of links.

Example:

I need code to randomly select and display ONE of these links. The exception being, IF article1.php is currently being viewed, I want it to be excluded from the random selection. That way only links to OTHER articles are seen on any given article.

```
http://mysite.com/article1.php
http://mysite.com/article2.php
http://mysite.com/article3.php
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong: `rand(0, count($urls)-1)`.

Comment: I don't get this part "want to make it so the current page is not included in the random rotation of links"... why do you add the current page's url to the links ?

Comment: Maher4Ever, the current page's link will be included because this code will be built into a footer.php page which is automatically included in each article, saving me from having to manually edit each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) with something like:

```
<?php
$links = array(array('url' => 'http://google.com', 'name'=>'google'),
               array('url' => 'http://hotmail.com', 'name' => 'hotmail'),
               array('url' => 'http://hawkee.com', 'name' => 'Hawkee'));
$num = array_rand($links);
$item = $links[$num];

printf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', $item['url'], $item['name'], $item['name']);
?>
```

Where links makes it easier to build an array. Nevertheless, I think we miss some details about how you grab your links.
What is the mean of "current page"? because the simplest way to do, is just not add the page to the array.

And the use of array_rand avoids confusion with size of array and so.

Edit: I suppose you use a database, so you may have an sql request like:

```
SELECT myfieldset FROM `articles` WHERE id = 'theid';
```

So you know the id of the current article. Now you just have to build an array with some other articles with a query like:

```
SELECT id FROM `articles` WHERE id NOT IN ('theid') ORDER BY RAND LIMIT 5
```

And build the candidate array with those results.

Comment: I think what he's saying though is that he wants to ensure that the same URL won't be used twice in a row.

Comment: @Kemo> I didn't get it since the given links are external websites.

Comment: I've got a bunch of pages (articles I've written), at the bottom of each one I want a randomly generated link to a DIFFERENT article (enticing the user to read something else). I don't want the URL of the current page/article to be shown as that defeats the purpose of the link.

Comment: @user179846: u could use Aif's solution and instead use your articles' urls and names in place of the ones used in the answer

Comment: Yeah. I just had those external links in there as placeholders. I will change those, but I want to ensure that the current page isn't seen down there.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you randomly choose a URL to display, pop it off of the array and store it in a temporary variable. Then, on the next rotation make your selection and THEN push the previously used URL back into the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastUrl = trim(file_get_contents('last_url.txt'));
while($lastUrl == ($randUrl = $urls[rand(0, count($urls) - 1)])){}
file_put_contents('last_url.txt', $randUrl);

// ...

echo $randUrl;
```

Ensures that on each page load, you will not receive the previous URL. This, however is just an example. You would want to incorporate file locking, exception handling (perhaps) or an entirely different storage medium (DB, etc.)

---

To ensure the URL is not the same as the current, this should do the trick:

```
// get current URL
$currentUrl = 'http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

// randomize URLs until you get one that doesn't match the current
while($currentUrl == ($randUrl = $urls[rand(0, count($urls) - 1)])){ }

echo $randUrl;
```

Google "PHP get current URL", and you'll get considerably more detailed ways to capture the current URL. For example, conditions on whether or not you're use *HTTPS*, to append an '*s*' to the protocol component.

Comment: This is beyond my level of expertise unfortunately.

Comment: Well, refer to the PHP manual, and I'm certain you'll quickly be able to understand the working parts of my example given. Regarding your comment to **Aif** about other articles vs. current article, you'll still need to employ a similar method to the one I've described. I'll amend my answer with a more relevant example.

Comment: Okay. Im starting to get this a bit more. Thanks for clarifying.

I don't need to worry about HTTPS or anything. Although I need a bit more help piecing it together.

Answer (score 0):

try the codes below :

```
$links = array(
            'http://mysite.com/article1.php',
            'http://mysite.com/article2.php',
            'http://mysite.com/article3.php',
            'http://mysite.com/article4.php',
            'http://mysite.com/article5.php'
       );

$currentPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$count = 0;
$currentIndex = NULL;
foreach($links as $link) {
    if(strpos($link, "/".$currentPage)>-1)  $currentIndex = $count;
    $count++; 
}

if($currentIndex) {
    do{
        $random = mt_rand(0, sizeof($links) - 1);
    } while($random==$currentIndex);
} else {
    $random = mt_rand(0, sizeof($links) - 1);
}

$random_link = $links[$random];
```